# sql query giving wrong counts

Tags: mysql, sql

when i apply the inner join query on 3 tables or more tables  getting sum of value is double compare to original value on the particular record. For example:2019-10-09 , sum=50 but it is showing sum=100 on 2019-10-09.

For example: date=2019-10-09 , sum=50 but it is showing sum=100 on date=2019-10-09.so here i'm expecting like this 2019-10-09 , sum=50.

Comment: where is your table and query ? Post it for clarity

Comment: Could you provide us with possibly an EER model and an example of your current query?

Comment: Check if there is double entry for the date = 2019-10-09.If so then you may try with distinct.

Comment: one of the tables joined, is having 2 records qualifying for the JOIN clause. This will result in duplicates...

Comment: @VB_isYoung you are half right.. Well JOIN can multiply aggregates (like `SUM()`) results it only can only  really happen when JOINing many-to-many or one-to-many relations..

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data, and SQL query, we are just guessing.

But the most likely explanation is that there is a semi-cross product... each row from a detail table is being matched to each row from another detail table.

If we remove the GROUP BY and aggregates, we can more easily see what is happening.

As an example:

```
SELECT m.m
     , a.a
     , t.t
  FROM ( SELECT 'm' AS m ) m
  JOIN ( SELECT 'alpha' AS a UNION ALL SELECT 'beta') a
  JOIN ( SELECT 'one' AS t UNION ALL SELECT 'two' UNION ALL SELECT 'three') t
 ORDER
    BY m.m
     , a.a
```

returns:

```
m   a       t
--  ------  ------
m   alpha   one     
m   alpha   two     
m   alpha   three
m   beta    one     
m   beta    two              
m   beta    three
```

Notice that we get six rows... three copies each of 'alpha' and 'beta', and two copies each of 'one', 'two' and 'three'.

That's because each row from `a` gets matched with each row from `t`.

(Also note that with an inner join, if `t` is empty (doesn't return any rows), then we wouldn't get any rows back at all. In the query above, we would get no rows at all; using an outer join, we could generate a zero count for rows from `a`. The issue isn't limited to just "duplicates".)

When we collapse rows with GROUP BY and aggregates...

```
SELECT m.m
     , COUNT(a.a) AS cnt_a
     , COUNT(t.t) AS cnt_t
  FROM ( SELECT 'm' AS m ) m
  JOIN ( SELECT 'alpha' AS a UNION ALL SELECT 'beta') a
  JOIN ( SELECT 'one' AS t UNION ALL SELECT 'two' UNION ALL SELECT 'three') t
 GROUP
    BY m.m
```

We see the "counts" of the rows seem to be inflated. There's only two rows in `a` and there are three rows in `t`, but we get a count of six.

```
m    cnt_a  cnt_t
---  -----  -----
m        6      6
```

---

The normal approaches to "fixing" this, to get a result like this returned:

```
m    cnt_a  cnt_t
---  -----  -----
m        2      3
```

are to pre-aggregate the counts, and then do the join, or we can count distinct rows (if we have an expression that returns a unique value for each row)

demonstration pattern of pre-aggregating counts in inline views

```
SELECT m.m
     , ca.cnt_a
     , ct.cnt_t
  FROM ( SELECT 'm' AS m ) m
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt_a
           FROM ( SELECT 'alpha' AS a UNION ALL SELECT 'beta') a
       ) ca
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM ( SELECT 'one' AS t UNION ALL SELECT 'two' UNION ALL SELECT 'three') t
       ) ct
```

demonstration of count distinct pattern

```
SELECT m.m
     , COUNT(DISTINCT a.a) AS cnt_a
     , COUNT(DISTINCT t.t) AS cnt_t
  FROM ( SELECT 'm' AS m ) m
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT 'alpha' AS a UNION ALL SELECT 'beta') a
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT 'one' AS t UNION ALL SELECT 'two' UNION ALL SELECT 'three') t
 GROUP
    BY m.m
```